# Dev-c++ send a file via ftp with the random file name

Tags: random, upload, ftp, filenames, dev-c++

I want to create a script  to send a file called office-data.txt on a ftp server, but I would like that this script, when the file is sent to a FTP server, must change its name randomly, only remotely. For example, office-data-12478.txt or office-data-22478.txt and the randomly generated name must never be the same each time the script starts. How I can make change the file name when it is sent to an FTP server ?

```
#include <string>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void stringtoint(const string &s, int &i){
   istringstream myStream(s);
   myStream>>i;
}

void sendLogIn(SOCKET _LSoc){
 char userbuffer[] = "username";                
 char passbuffer[] = "password";                
 char username[] = "USER ";
 char password[] = "PASS ";
 char servermessage[1000];

 strcat(username, userbuffer);
 strcat(username, "\r\n");

 send(_LSoc, username, strlen(username), 0);
 Sleep(1000);
    recv(_LSoc, servermessage, 1000, 0);

 strcat(password, passbuffer);
 strcat(password, "\r\n");

 send(_LSoc, password, strlen(password), 0);
 Sleep(1000);
    recv(_LSoc, servermessage, 1000, 0);
}

int sendConnInfo(SOCKET _CSoc){
 char servermessage[10000];
 char ftpmessage[50];
 string message;
 string portbuffer;
    string port1;
 string port2;
 size_t position;
 size_t position2;
 int port;
 int portbuf;
 int _portbuf;

 send(_CSoc, "TYPE I\r\n", 8, 0);
 Sleep(1000);
    recv(_CSoc, servermessage, 10000, 0);
 Sleep(1000);
 Sleep(1000);
    send(_CSoc, "PASV\r\n", 6, 0);
 Sleep(1000);
    recv(_CSoc, ftpmessage, 50, 0);

 message = ftpmessage;
 position = message.find("Mode");
 portbuffer = message.substr(position+21);

    position = portbuffer.find(",");
    position2 = portbuffer.find(">");

    port1 = portbuffer.substr(0, position);
    port2 = portbuffer.substr(position+1, position2-1);

    stringtoint(port1, portbuf);
    stringtoint(port2, _portbuf);

    port = portbuf*256;
    port = port + _portbuf;
    return port;
}

void sendFileRequest(SOCKET _FSoc){
     send(_FSoc, "STOR test.txt\r\n", strlen("STOR test.txt\r\n"), 0);
     Sleep(1000);
}

BOOL ftpSocket(int port){
     SOCKET sock;
     SOCKADDR_IN pasvserver;
     char servermessage[MAX_PATH];
     HANDLE HFile;
     DWORD read;
     char *buffer;
     char filename[] = "C:\\test.txt";
     int connectionerror2;
     int trycount2 = 2;     

     sock = socket(2, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
     if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET){
   WSACleanup();
   return 0;
  }

 pasvserver.sin_family = 2;
 pasvserver.sin_port = htons(port);                                
 pasvserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("66.220.9.50");           //Once again the drivehq ftp server

 connectionerror2 = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&pasvserver, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
     while(connectionerror2 == SOCKET_ERROR){
            connectionerror2 = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&pasvserver, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            trycount2++;
            if(trycount2 = 10){
                         closesocket(sock);
                         WSACleanup();
                         return 0;
            }
    }


    HFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    buffer = (char *)malloc(4096);
    SetFilePointer(HFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    while(ReadFile(HFile, buffer, 4096, &read, NULL) && read > 0){
         send(sock, buffer, read, 0);
    }

    return true;   
}


int sendFile(){
 FreeConsole();
 WSAData WData;
 SOCKET FSoc;
 SOCKADDR_IN server;
 int connectionerror;
 int trycount = 2;
 char servermessage[MAX_PATH];
 int port;


 WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WData);
 FSoc = socket(2, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        if(FSoc == INVALID_SOCKET){
   WSACleanup();
   return 0;
  }

 server.sin_family = 2;
 server.sin_port = htons(21);
 server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("66.220.9.50"); //this is the drivehq ftp server address.


 connectionerror = connect(FSoc, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
     while(connectionerror == SOCKET_ERROR){
            connectionerror = connect(FSoc, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
            trycount++;
            if(trycount = 10){
                         closesocket(FSoc);
                         WSACleanup();
                         return 0;
            }
    }

 recv(FSoc, servermessage, sizeof(servermessage),0);

 sendLogIn(FSoc);
 Sleep(1000);  //give the server and the client sometime to deal with the influx of new messages
               //so that data for the ip doesnt get mixed up.
    port = sendConnInfo(FSoc);
    sendFileRequest(FSoc);
    ftpSocket(port);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
int main(){
   sendFile();
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please be more careful when pasting code. However, you should note that [SO] is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you stop using [Dev-C++.](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) It is really outdated, and the latest beta was published more than 10 years ago:

> [February 21th 2005 : Dev-C++ 5 Beta 9.2 (4.9.9.2) released !](http://www.bloodshed.net/index.html)

You should try [NetBeans C/C++](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/) bundle and a compiler/linker (gcc/g++/make) from [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). For more information on how to setup such a development environment, look at this link [here](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html). Also you can try [Eclipse CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/) or even [Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/) or the newest [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/).

**Now for your program and the code.**

Although your program works, I found some minor errors that kept it from working properly when I compiled it and run it.

You want to upload a file to a FTP server and save it with a unique filename to a remote path.

You can simple use [`STOU`](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#STOU) ftp command instead of [`STOR`](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#STOR) and the ftp server will save the file with a unique filename under the current working directory. So, you’ll have to change `sendFileRequest` procedure to use `CWD` to change to directory to the directory we want to save the file, and then just use `STOU` without any parameters and the server will handle the rest and save with a unique filename. For example, *Pure-FTP* sever generates a filename like this `pureftpd.583c3777.dd.0000`.

The `sendFileRequest` procedure will become like this:

```cpp
void sendFileRequest(SOCKET _FSoc){
    char cwdCmd[MAX_PATH] = "CWD /web/share/tmp/\r\n";
    send(_FSoc,  cwdCmd, strlen(cwdCmd), 0);
    Sleep(1000);

    //char stor[] = "STOR /web/share/tmp/test.txt\r\n";
    char stor[] = "STOU\r\n";
    send(_FSoc, stor, strlen(stor), 0);
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Beware, some ftp server do not support `STOU` command.

Now, if you want to control the filenames and generate the names based on some criteria, you’ll have to read the list of files in the directory you want to upload the file and then generate a unique filename that does not exists into the list of files of the remote directory.

We want to issue an ftp command to get the filenames of the current directory back. [`NLST`](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#NLST) ftp command is what we want, as it sends a buffer containing text data with line feeds separators for each file; a list of all the file/folder names (*only filenames, no more data*) in the current working directory. We also need to open a data connection using passive mode to retrieve that data. Also I noticed sometimes although the file was created with the unique name to the remote server path, there was no data transferred at all. That’s happening because I was executing the program very fast and the previous ftp sessions was not closed properly with a [`QUIT`](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#QUIT) command. When I added the `QUIT` command at the end of the process, all the zero data file transfer issues were gone.

**Code level issues and remarks**

- I have changed `TYPE I` image/binary to `TYPE A` text, because most ftp servers do fix the line feeds `CR LF` when transferring text files from unix to windows format and vice versa.
- You have to always close data connections by using [`shutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [`closesocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx) to the data socket connection, or else the server can abort your data transferred.
- You are having a function to convert a `std::string` to integer, but you can also use `std::stoi` if you tell the compiler to use *C++11* standards by using the `-std=c++11` option.
- When you are using `recv` to read the server response, you must always null terminate response buffer string by using `recv` return value, or only process the number of bytes `recv` returns.
- The program has no status reading behavior, which can result in many errors and a total failure. A proper ftp application behavior must always depend on the responses server sends to the command connection. For example, if the ftp server has reached the maximum client limit, then your program won’t know that and will continue to issue commands until it fails or ends. The program should not and cannot continue if such errors occur.

**Compiler options**

`-std=c++11` for `std::stoi`

**Linker options**

`-lws2_32` to include the cygwin `libws2_32.a` required for `winsock2.h`

**Pseudo code**

- Initialize ftp server command connection
- Send ftp login information
- Generate unique filename

  - Read the remote directory filenames
  - Generate random names until we don’t have the name to the files list
- Send the file with the unique filename to the server

For the unique filename, I just used a char array filled with characters `[A-Za-z0-0]`. You can also choose if you’ll use local file extension to make the check and add it to the end of the unique filename:

```cpp
string generateUniqueFilename(SOCKET _FSoc,
                              int port,
                              string remotePath,
                              bool useLocalFileExtension,
                              string localFile)
```

For example, setting `useLocalFileExtension` to `true` when we have a local `.txt` file, will result having a unique filename with a `.txt` extension `O3xh8p939YN4hV.txt`.

**My final program**

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


#define REMOTE_FTP_HOST_IP "x.x.x.x"
#define REMOTE_FTP_USERNAME "username"              
#define REMOTE_FTP_PASSWORD "password"

#define ECHO_FTP_RESPONSE 1 // Set to 0 to disable ftp responses output

using namespace std;


// Declarations ---------------------------------------------------

void echoResponse(string);
void echoResponse(LPSTR);
void recvResponseAndEcho(SOCKET, LPSTR, int);
void recvResponseAndEcho(SOCKET);
string generateRandomFilename(int);
int readSocketData(int, LPSTR, int);
string generateUniqueFilename(SOCKET, int, string, bool, string);
void sendLogIn(SOCKET socket);
void sendFileRequest(SOCKET, string, string);
void sendTypeICmd(SOCKET);
void sendTypeACmd(SOCKET);
int sendPasvCmd(SOCKET);
void sendQuitCmd(SOCKET);
BOOL ftpSocket(string, int);
int sendFile(string, string);


// Program entry point --------------------------------------------

int main(){
    sendFile("C:\\test.txt", "/remote/ftp/path/");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void echoResponse(string response) {
    if(ECHO_FTP_RESPONSE) {
        string respclean = response.erase(response.find_last_not_of(" \t\n\r") + 1);
        cout << respclean << endl;
    }
}

void echoResponse(LPSTR response) {
    if(ECHO_FTP_RESPONSE) {
        string respstr = response;
        echoResponse(respstr);
    }
}

void recvResponseAndEcho(SOCKET socket, LPSTR buffer, int bufsize) {
    int nread = recv(socket, buffer, bufsize, 0);
    *(buffer + nread) = 0;
    echoResponse(buffer);
}

void recvResponseAndEcho(SOCKET socket) {
    char srvResponse[4096];
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket, (LPSTR)&srvResponse, sizeof(srvResponse));
}

// Generate o random filename using an array of charactres [A-Za-z0-9]
string generateRandomFilename(int length) {
    string rndFilename;
    char fileChars[] = 
             "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
             "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
             "0123456789";
    int fileCharsLength = strlen(fileChars);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        rndFilename += fileChars[rand() % fileCharsLength];

    return rndFilename;
}

int readSocketData(int port, LPSTR buffer, int buffer_size) {
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN pasvserver;
    int connectionerror2;
    int trycount2 = 2;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET){
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    pasvserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    pasvserver.sin_port = htons(port);                                
    pasvserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(REMOTE_FTP_HOST_IP);

    connectionerror2 = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&pasvserver, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    while(connectionerror2 == SOCKET_ERROR){
        connectionerror2 = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&pasvserver, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        trycount2++;
        if(trycount2 = 10) {
            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int result = recv(sock, buffer, buffer_size, 0);
    shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(sock);
    return result;
}

string generateUniqueFilename(SOCKET _FSoc, int port, string remotePath, bool useLocalFileExtension, string localFile) {
    string newFilename;
    char cwd[MAX_PATH];
    char cmd[7] = "NLST\r\n";
    char listFilesBuffer[4096];
    char servermessage[2048];
    int listFilesBufferReadLength;

    strcpy(cwd, "CWD ");
    strcat(cwd, remotePath.c_str());
    strcat(cwd, "\r\n");
    send(_FSoc,  cwd, strlen(cwd), 0);
    Sleep(1000);

    recvResponseAndEcho(_FSoc, (LPSTR)&servermessage, sizeof(servermessage));
    Sleep(1000);

    send(_FSoc, cmd, strlen(cmd), 0);
    listFilesBufferReadLength = readSocketData(port, listFilesBuffer, 4096);

    if(listFilesBufferReadLength > 0) {
        std::istringstream fileLines(listFilesBuffer);
        string fileLine, localFileExtension;
        std::vector<std::string> filesList;

        while (std::getline(fileLines, fileLine)) {
            // Trim whitespaces from each line
            fileLine = fileLine.erase(fileLine.find_last_not_of(" \t\n\r") + 1);
            if(fileLine != "." && fileLine != "..")
                // Save to a vector or strings if it's not current and level up directory
                filesList.push_back(fileLine);
        }

        if(useLocalFileExtension) {
            int dotPos = localFile.find_last_of(".");
            localFileExtension = dotPos > 0 ? localFile.substr(dotPos) : "";
        }

        vector<string>::iterator fileFind;

        do {
            // Generate random filenames of 14 characters length
            // untill the filename does not exist on the remote FTP server path
            newFilename = generateRandomFilename(14);
            if(useLocalFileExtension)
                newFilename += localFileExtension;
        } while((fileFind = std::find(filesList.begin(), filesList.end(), newFilename)) != filesList.end());
    }

    return newFilename;
}

void sendLogIn(SOCKET socket) {               
    char userCmd[128] = "USER ";
    char passCmd[128] = "PASS ";

    strcat(userCmd, REMOTE_FTP_USERNAME);
    strcat(userCmd, "\r\n");
    send(socket, userCmd, strlen(userCmd), 0);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket);

    strcat(passCmd, REMOTE_FTP_PASSWORD);
    strcat(passCmd, "\r\n");
    send(socket, passCmd, strlen(passCmd), 0);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket);
}

void sendFileRequest(SOCKET socket, string remoteDirectory, string storFilename) {
    char cwdCmd[MAX_PATH] = "CWD ";
    char storCmd[MAX_PATH] = "STOR ";
    //char stouCmd[] = "STOU\r\n";

    // Change current working directory
    strcat(cwdCmd, remoteDirectory.c_str());
    strcat(cwdCmd, "\r\n");
    send(socket,  cwdCmd, strlen(cwdCmd), 0);
    Sleep(1000);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket);

    // Send stor ftp command
    strcat(storCmd, storFilename.c_str());
    strcat(storCmd, "\r\n");
    send(socket, storCmd, strlen(storCmd), 0);

    // Send stou ftp command insted of stor
    //send(socket, stouCmd, strlen(stouCmd), 0);
}


// Image/binary type
void sendTypeICmd(SOCKET socket) {
    char typeCmd[] = "TYPE I\r\n";
    send(socket, typeCmd, strlen(typeCmd), 0);
    Sleep(1000);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket);
}

// Text type
void sendTypeACmd(SOCKET socket) {
    char typeCmd[] = "TYPE A\r\n";
    send(socket, typeCmd, strlen(typeCmd), 0);
    Sleep(1000);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket);
}

int sendPasvCmd(SOCKET socket) {
    int result = -1;
    char pasvCmd[] = "PASV\r\n";
    char srvResponse[4096];

    send(socket, pasvCmd, strlen(pasvCmd), 0);
    Sleep(1000);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket, (LPSTR)&srvResponse, sizeof(srvResponse));

    // Read the pasv response, something like:
    // 227 Entering Passive Mode (x,x,x,x,y,y)
    // where x are the ip bytes and y are the port bytes
    string pasvMessage = srvResponse;
    int modeStart = pasvMessage.find("Mode");

    if(modeStart > 0) {
        int parenthesisStart = pasvMessage.find("(", modeStart);
        if(parenthesisStart > 0) {
            string currentPasvByte;
            char currentChar;
            int currentCharPos = parenthesisStart,
                currentPasvByteIndex = 0,
                highByte = -1,
                lowByte = -1;

            do {
                currentChar = pasvMessage[++currentCharPos];
                if(currentChar == ',' || currentChar == ')') {
                    if(currentPasvByteIndex == 4)
                        highByte = stoi(currentPasvByte);
                    else if(currentPasvByteIndex == 5)
                        lowByte = stoi(currentPasvByte);
                    currentPasvByteIndex++;
                    currentPasvByte = "";
                } else
                    currentPasvByte += currentChar;
            } while(currentChar != ')');

            // Assemble the port number by joing hi and lo port number bytes
            if(highByte != -1 && lowByte != -1)
                result = (highByte << 8) | lowByte;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void sendQuitCmd(SOCKET socket) {
    char quitCmd[] = "QUIT\r\n";
    send(socket, quitCmd, strlen(quitCmd), 0);
    recvResponseAndEcho(socket);
}

BOOL ftpSocket(string localFile, int port) {
    BOOL result = false;
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN pasvserver;
    int connectionerror2;
    int trycount2 = 2;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET){
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    pasvserver.sin_family = AF_INET;
    pasvserver.sin_port = htons(port);                                
    pasvserver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(REMOTE_FTP_HOST_IP); //Once again the drivehq ftp server

    connectionerror2 = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&pasvserver, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    while(connectionerror2 == SOCKET_ERROR){
        connectionerror2 = connect(sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&pasvserver, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        trycount2++;
        if(trycount2 = 10) {
            closesocket(sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return false;
        }
    }

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(localFile.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);;

    if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD read;
        char buffer[4096];
        SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

        while(ReadFile(hFile, buffer, 4096, &read, NULL) && read > 0) {
            send(sock, buffer, read, 0);
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        result = true;   
    }

    shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(sock);
    return result;
}

int sendFile(string localFile, string remotePath) {
    FreeConsole();
    WSAData WData;
    SOCKET FSoc;
    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    int connectionerror;
    int trycount = 2;
    int port;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &WData);
    FSoc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(FSoc == INVALID_SOCKET){
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(21);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(REMOTE_FTP_HOST_IP); //this is the drivehq ftp server address.                                                    

    connectionerror = connect(FSoc, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    while(connectionerror == SOCKET_ERROR){
        connectionerror = connect(FSoc, (LPSOCKADDR)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        trycount++;
        if(trycount = 10){
            closesocket(FSoc);
            WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    recvResponseAndEcho(FSoc);

    sendLogIn(FSoc);
    Sleep(1000);  //give the server and the client sometime to deal with the influx of new messages
    //so that data for the ip doesnt get mixed up.

    // Send typea command to transfer text data.
    // It works better for windows to unix text files transfer, bacause it fixes
    // the line endnings CR, LF on most ftp servers
    // Use typei command for binary data.
    //sendTypeACmd(FSoc);
    sendTypeACmd(FSoc);

    // Open passing mode for the files list data
    port = sendPasvCmd(FSoc);

    // Generate a unique filename that does not exists on the FTP remote directory
    string filename = generateUniqueFilename(FSoc, port, remotePath, true, localFile);

    // Open passing mode for the file transfer data
    port = sendPasvCmd(FSoc);

    sendFileRequest(FSoc, remotePath, filename);
    ftpSocket(localFile, port);
    recvResponseAndEcho(FSoc);

    sendQuitCmd(FSoc);
    shutdown(FSoc, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(FSoc);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```